# NFL #1 offense getting shut out in a half in the postseason

Tags: trivia, american-football, nfl

The Kansas City Chiefs had the [#1](https://247sports.com/nfl/tennessee-titans/ContentGallery/NFL-offensive-scoring-rankings-2018-121722415/#121722415_1) offense of the 2018 regular season. The New England Patriots shut out the Cheifs 14 - 0 in the first half of the AFC Championship game. The Patriots eventually beat the Chiefs 37 - 31 in OT.

How many times has the #1 offense in the regular season been held scoreless in any half of a postseason game?

Comment: The Denver Broncos during Super Bowl 48. Not only did they have the #1 scoring offense that season, but the #1 scoring offense of all-time.